# Java Coding Standards - all variable names in lower case

Tags: java, jpa, coding-style, standards, pojo

We are generating Entity Classes from database tables using Netbeans utility, now here we have ability to do it vise-a-verse. Like from Table to Entity POJOs and reverse, so that when we make any change in Entity POJO - we will get updated SQL.

Eclipse too have similar utility available for JPA but it does not do reverse, now here the problem is while generating Entity POJO from tables we don't get a choice for naming conventions. We get all field-names in lower case and same goes for class where nothing is camel-cased just first letter in upper-case while everything else in lower-case.

Now this seems to be creating a problem with coding standards that we have defined as it requires us to use camel-casing for variable and method names.

So we had discussion with team and one thought was to keep all variables in lower-case throughout project, personally to which I do not agree as it makes code very much unreadable as we are not planning to use underscores to separate words. You can give your vote on this standard.

What do you think is best way out? Is there any Entity POJO generator available which converts both ways and still has ability to convert into camel-casing from db table names when it finds under-score?

Comment: "You can give your vote on this standard." - sir, this site is about facts, not opinions. The best we could do is to gather some statistics or list the downsides

Comment: Personally, I don't like underscore_case, but I still use it when camelCase is not available.

Comment: You can grab a copy of the [Code Conventions for the Java Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to stop and move to standard java naming conventions immediately:

1. variables and methods names start with lower case
2. Class and interface names start with upper case
3. Camel convention is used. No underscores except constants (see later)
4. public final static fields names are all capital with underscores (like `#define` in C). The same is recommended for `enum` fields (but this recommendation is not so strict)

I am sorry if I forgot something. But following naming and coding conventions applicable by most of developers is very important. First, these conventions are based on very large experience. Do not think that you can improve them. You can't. I can't too. :)
Second following coding conventions makes your code understandable for other people and avoid silly mistakes.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem is with the framework messing the convention by assuming the name was a single word. Did I read wrong?

Comment: the question asks for entity pojo generator

Comment: Tool basically.. I am new to project and hate when people don't follow standard. I wanted some improvements to be done so that I love to see code but the excuse about Netbeans (and Entity generator) is given by legacy team. I just verified that if you use underscores in table fields and names it does camel-casing... So it's just a matter of making that change and understanding that Java standard is to be followed and not to be manipulated for the good. I am trying to trigger this change as merely 2/3 months been spent on the project and if we fall back 1 more week things will be beautiful.

Comment: @Dharmavir then it seems obvious - use underscores in the database so that you get camel case in the object model.

Answer (score 2):

I used [dali](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/) with eclipse for entity generation, would be surprised if you could not set the [naming you require](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/tasks006.htm#BABBAGFI).

Also, I imagine intellij allows you to also do this as required.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting dali, I will check this out.

Answer (score 2):

> What do you think is best way out?

Follow the Java style conventions.  Period.

> Is there any Entity POJO generator available which converts both ways and still has ability to convert into camel-casing from db table names when it finds under-score?

I don't know.

But if you can't find one, take an existing *open source* generator and *modify* it to do what you want.  And then contribute your patches back to the project so that other people can benefit from your work.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] one thought was to keep all variables in lower-case throughout project [...]

Forget this. You are in Java land. This means that all other frameworks will not adhere to that standard and hence you will never have only one, clean coding style. And one of the beauties of Java is, that there is *The One Style* which makes reading foreign code much easier.

So instead spreading that disease you should try to contain it into the smallest space possible - in your case the stuff generated by the tool. The next step is to improve or remove that tool.